# Using RemoteAPI to access the live datastore from my dev server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, remoteapi

I've got an app that, in some situation I can't reproduce, locks up both Firefox and Chrome.  I have no insight into what's causing the problem.  I can't get any information because both browsers just lock up - even firebug and Chrome's developer tools freeze.  Impressive, I know!

Anyway, I thought I'd run the app with the debugger hooked up in eclipse, but using RemoteApi to use the actual data so I can see what's happening here.  I wrote a ServletFilter:

```
public class RemoteApiFilter implements Filter {

    RemoteApiOptions options;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {
            RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
            installer.install(options);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            installer.uninstall();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        options = new RemoteApiOptions().server(
                config.getInitParameter("host"), 443).credentials(
                config.getInitParameter("email"),
                config.getInitParameter("password"));
    }

}
```

I run every request through this filter, and I thought this would make my whole app work like normal, but with the live, production datastore instead of with the development datastore.  But it didn't work! Instead, on the very first call I make to the datastore api, I get some sort of threading access violation exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:191)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:336)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:626)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DefaultThreadFactory.newThread(Executors.java:542)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addThread(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:672)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addIfUnderCorePoolSize(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:697)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:652)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:92)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiDelegate.makeAsyncCall(RemoteApiDelegate.java:98)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxy.java:184)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.makeAsyncCall(DatastoreApiHelper.java:81)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:306)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingAsyncDatastoreService.getFromDatastore(CachingAsyncDatastoreService.java:111)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingAsyncDatastoreService.get(CachingAsyncDatastoreService.java:372)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.AsyncObjectifyImpl.get(AsyncObjectifyImpl.java:68)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.AsyncObjectifyImpl.find(AsyncObjectifyImpl.java:192)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.AsyncObjectifyImpl.get(AsyncObjectifyImpl.java:101)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.AsyncObjectifyImpl.get(AsyncObjectifyImpl.java:124)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ObjectifyImpl.get(ObjectifyImpl.java:63)
    at com.activegrade.server.data.DataCoordinatorAppengineImpl.verifyUser(DataCoordinatorAppengineImpl.java:471)
    at com.activegrade.server.servlets.MainPageChooser.doGet(MainPageChooser.java:54)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.activegrade.server.filter.RemoteAPIFilter.doFilter(RemoteAPIFilter.java:25)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I'm using Objectify and Resteasy but otherwise this is a pretty plain setup.  I'm totally stumped about what to try next.

Is this a good way to try to debug my GWT application with live data on GAE?  What's going wrong, and what should I try next to get more information?

Comment: Have you tried using the bulkloader to download your data and upload it into the dev_appserver, instead?

Comment: Yes, but it's about a gigabyte of data, the transfer takes forever (and costs dollars), and my dev machines run out of memory.  When I just want to look at a particular user's data, it'd be great to just plug into the live servers.  If I can't get this to work I'll write code to just download the relevant data (< 0.5 Mb) but that's a pain and error-prone in itself.

Comment: You're likely getting the exception because the dev server enforces restrictions to emulate the production environment, which you're attempting to evade. I think you'll have a sufficiently hard time setting this up that you'd be better off just downloading the data you need. It's not clear to me how server-side debugging will help you, though - isn't the issue with the client?

Comment: Yes, absolutely it's with the client. I'm in the position of not knowing where the bug is coming from - I need the specific data to reproduce the problem. So, the only reason I need the live data is to find the bug in the client side.  Oh well - it may be useful to me to write a per-user download tool anyway... it'll be nice to be able to muck around with it.  As ever, thanks Nick.

Comment: Have you considered fetching the page with curl/wget, and saving it locally? Then you can examine it and reproduce the bug at will.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221797/debug-in-localhost-using-deployed-database/20224277?noredirect=1#20224277

Comment: Riley, do you have any suggestion right now? "OAuth-based authorization not supported for clients running on App Engine" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815315/how-to-debug-server-code-in-eclipse-on-deployed-appengine-database