# How to debug server code in eclipse on deployed appengine database?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, oauth, remoteapi

I have a Google AppEngine (Java) project in Eclipse. I want to debug my local code in Eclipse but use the deployed database on AppEngine. Until now I use Remote API with username/password (old way)

This method will be deprecated and I want to use OAuth but when I try to use it, it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: OAuth-based authorization not supported for clients running on App Engine
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiOptions.getOrCreateHttpTransportForOAuth(RemoteApiOptions.java:359)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiOptions.useApplicationDefaultCredential(RemoteApiOptions.java:162)
```

Everthing is fine when I run a simple Java client app that uses remote api in Eclipse. But if the client is AppEngine development environment in Eclipse, it doesn't work.

How can I debug the server code in eclipse using appengine database?

Bug report: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12556

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi#configuring_remote_api_on_an_app_engine_client), you need to add **appengine-remote-api.jar** from **${SDK_ROOT}/lib/appengine-remote-api.jar** to your WEB-INF/lib directory (or add it to your Maven dependencies) before this will work.

**Update:** Indeed, it looks like OAuth from App Engine with Remote API has not yet been implemented. I would assume this will change before ClientLogin is fully deprecated, but for now I would recommend opening a feature request on the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

One possible workaround would be to create a regular console application that connects to the Remote API (as per the example in the docs) and can act as a proxy for your App Engine application running on the development server.

Comment: Adding jar unfortunately does not work. Could you please explain more about your possible workaround? I can create a regular console app but how can it act as a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

This is [expected](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/tools/remoteapi/RemoteApiOptions.java?r=529#316), as value returned by `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment()` will not be `null`, but `com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalHttpRequestEnvironment` object. For development server you'll have to use old style (username/password) for now.

Comment: But the old style support ends on January 20th, 2016. So my question is: "Is there any alternative to OAuth or any other way of debugging the server code in eclipse using appengine database?" Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what my colleagues Adam and Nikita previously said, I can officially confirm that the Google Cloud Engineering Team is determined to provide a solution to all reasonable use-cases which are affected by the [ClientLogin shutdown](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/clientlogin) before its deadline.

Presumably, the Remote API solution will be available in the upcoming releases 1.9.31/32, although this is just an assumption and there's no ETA for it yet.

As an alternative, you can [access Cloud Datastore using Protobufs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/) remotely using service account credentials, which might fit your needs for the moment.

***UPDATE 2016/01/21:***

The team has extended the ClientLogin shutdown deadline to April 12, 2016.

***UPDATE 2016/04/12:***

As mentioned before, the fix was properly applied and available in the latest versions of the SDK and gcloud. Remote API can now be used again with OAuth for app-to-app (or devserver-to-app) connection.